# Rectangle split in tikz graphs using simple necklace layout

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I am trying to split my rectangle nodes by half with *rectangle split* command, but I am getting compiling error for unknown command. What I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={210mm,297mm},
 left=5mm,
 right=5mm,
 top=20mm,
 bottom=20mm,
 }

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\usegdlibrary{circular}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={rectangle,rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,rectangle split part fill={red!30,white!20}, draw, minimum size=0.75cm}, node sep=5cm]
\graph [simple necklace layout]
    {

        1,2,6,4,5,3;
  1->[xshift=1pt,yshift=2pt]3 -> 2, 3 ->[xshift=-1pt,yshift=-2pt]1 -> 2;
  3 -> 5 -> 6 ->[xshift=-1pt,yshift=-2pt] 4 ->[xshift=1pt,yshift=-2pt]5, 5 ->[xshift=-1pt,yshift=2pt] 4 ->[xshift=1pt,yshift=2pt] 6;

    };


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{shapes}` and compile with LuaLaTeX. Just guessing arround. You have to show us the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the Ti*k*Z library `shapes` in order to do a `rectangle split`:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    %total={210mm,297mm}, % <= that looks a bit doubled, doesn't it?
    left=5mm,
    right=5mm,
    top=20mm,
    bottom=20mm
    }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    ,graphdrawing
    ,graphs
    ,shapes % <= added new library here!
    }
\usegdlibrary{circular}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    ,>=stealth
    ,every node/.style={%
        ,rectangle
        ,rectangle split
        ,rectangle split parts=2
        ,rectangle split part fill={red!30,white} % <= it is enough to have white here...
        ,draw
        ,minimum size=0.75cm
        }
    ,node sep=5cm
    ]
    \graph [simple necklace layout]
        {%      
        1,2,6,4,5,3;
        1->[xshift=1pt,yshift=2pt]3 -> 2, 3 ->[xshift=-1pt,yshift=-2pt]1 -> 2;
        3 -> 5 -> 6 ->[xshift=-1pt,yshift=-2pt] 4 ->[xshift=1pt,yshift=-2pt]5, 5 ->[xshift=-1pt,yshift=2pt] 4 ->[xshift=1pt,yshift=2pt] 6;      
        };  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```